# How to resize the width of Nautilus sidebar?

Tags: nautilus

I am using Ubuntu 12.10.

I am unable to see the bookmarks in Nautilus, although right clicking on "Personal Ordner"(German version) opens a list of the bookmarks. The corrupted screen (see the screenshot below) shows the bookmarks in a sub-window only about 5 mm wide!

[image: Corrupted Nautilus window]

I have tried reinstalling Nautilus with Synaptic, without however any success.

Any ideas about how to resize the width of Nautilus' sidebar?

Answer (score 1):

#### Drag the sidebar to resize

Size of sidebar in nautilus is adjustable. You somehow might have changed it accidentally and it remembers your last modified settings. You can easily change it by dragging the sidebar to normal width.

---

#### Alternate Method - use dconf Editor

- Install **dconf Editor**. It's package name is [dconf-tools [image: Install dconf-tools]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/dconf-tools).
- Launch dconf-editor using dash.
- Select *org → gnome → nautilus → window-state* from left panel.
- Set the value of *sidebar-width* to default.

[image: dconf-editor]

Comment: No problem! If this solves your problem, you can mark it as accepted answer.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately dragging didn't work and the settings with dconf-editor were unchanged at 148, so nothing to change. I set to 148 as default just the same, & re booted, but am still with the (nearly) hidden sidebar.

Comment: @Aditya, IgnitE Could it be that Unity does not use all/any  of the org → gnome → nautilus → window-state > sidebar-width settings?? My sidebar window is so small, it's simply not useable. An upgrade to Nautilus 3.6 brought exactly no change

Comment: @DavidWalker: Is there anything in ~/.config/nautilus? If yes delete it.

Comment: @Aditya rm -R ~/.gconf/apps/nautilus didn't work, file/folder not found

Comment: @IgnitE: ~/.config/nautilus deleted, logged in again, no change, sidebar panel still too small

Comment: @Aditya, IgnitE: Could it be that Unity does not use all/any of the org → gnome → nautilus → window-state > sidebar-width settings??

Comment: OK got it fixed 1.purged and reinstalled with Nautilus 3.6, still not working 2. Read another contribution, saying  that F9 fixes it. It didn't but it freed the separator for dragging the window to a greater size-weird

Answer (score 0):

I have a same problem. I solve it by deleted some unneeded bookmarks.
Left click on Ubuntu desktop, then click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> on keyboard, choose some bookmark on the left pane that you don't need and click <kbd>Del</kbd> on keyboard. Try open your drive and resize the sidebar.